# Android: run animation while loading stuff

Tags: java, android, multithreading, animation, user-interface

I'm reading a lot of files from the network. This takes quite a long time. Because of this i want to run a little animation (like a progress animation). But the animation only starts when the other stuff is finished. How can i run the animation on the UI Thread (in a Dialog!)?

```
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) ivAnimation.getBackground();
animation.start();
```

Comment: Where is your network code run? In a separate thread or the UI thread? In the UI thread this can't work as it is blocked by the network code.

Comment: I don't use a different thread. All code runs on the default thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main thread cannot be simultaneously downloading data and running an animation, also you cannot modify the UI from a background thread. As a result, you cannot "run an animation in the background", your animations and all UI tasks must be executed on the main thread while your data is downloading on a background thread.

Android, fortunately, has AsyncTask just for this purpose...

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<MyData>>() {
  @Override public void onPreExecute() {
    startMyAnimation();
  }

  @Override public List<MyData> doInBackground(String... urls) {
    List<MyData> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0;
    publishProgress(counter);
    for(String url : urls) {
      data.add(getMyDataFromNetwork(url));
      publishProgress(++counter);
    }
    return data;
  }

  @Override public void onPostExecute(List<MyData> result) {
    stopMyAnimation();
    updateMyUiWithData(result);
  }

  @Override public void onProgressUpdate(Integer filesDownloaded) {
    updateUiWithFileCount(filesDownloaded);
  }
}.execute(url1, url2, url3, etc);
```

Comment: A last little question: How can I update the UI from the doInBackground()?

Comment: You cannot, you must update the UI from a method executing on the UI thread. If there are multiple parts to your download step, you can use the "publishUpdate()" method of async task... I've update the example to show how to use it...

Answer (score 2):

Check out Volley framework for performing long running network related operation. It's easy to use and very good, built exactly for networking in the background.

A general rule in Android (or any other GUI applications) is to never run long running operation on the UI thread. In android this will get you ANR's and will kill your app.

In general here's what U should do:

1. Start the download using Volley or an AsyncTask or something else (Will run in background).
2. Create and show a progress dialog to display to user (On UI thread).
3. Once an answer/response is received, call dialog.dismiss() on the progress dialog.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but this wasn't my question. I want to run the animation in the background. Not the other stuff. I don't download something. I do a lot of other (different) stuff. Is there no way to run the animation in a background task?

Comment: Well animations should run on UI only. Still, you said you are performing network related stuff. This doesn't necessarily mean downloading but as far as network is concerned, it should run in the background and then only publish the results to UI.

Comment: What is the advantage? Because rewrite the whole network part is a lot of work. Is it not possible to let the animation run in a background process or something else?

Comment: Look at it this way - the main thread (The UI thread) can do only one thing at one time. If you run your networking logic on the UI thread it's gonna do ONLY that, and your app will not be responding to any other input from the user (Like when the user touch the screen) until the network communication will finish.

Android has a built in mechanism that will kill your app if it is not responding for more then a few seconds.

So just to make it clear again - anything related to UI like views, animations and so, should be done on the main thread (the UI thread). The rest, on different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use  Asynchronous task for this.  [Asynchronous task in android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

In onPreExecute() method of Asynchronous task show animation, progress bar or anything whatever you want to show. Used doInBackground for downloading the stuffs.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work. Maybe you have a better example? The only thing i want is to run a little animation in the background.